# Machine-specific code-coverage issue

Tags: c#, code-coverage

I have two dev machines, both running VS2010 SP1, used for a .NET 4.0 C# solution.  Machine 1 runs code coverage on my unit tests without problem.  I'm loading the same solution and running the same tests on Machine 2, and at some point recently, it changed from working fine to now always returning the following in the Code Coverage Results window: "Empty results generated: none of the instrumented binary was used. Look at test run details for any instrumentation problems."

I have repeatedly created new Test Settings on both machines using the identical steps.  I've copied over Machine 1 settings to Machine 2.  Neither has changed the issue on Machine 2.

What sort of machine-specific setting(s) might I check for to find the cause of this issue?

Comment: What tool does the code coverage, VS? Presumably the answer will be specific to that tool.

Comment: Yes, this is the native VS2010 code coverage tool.  The settings for Tools > Options > TestTools are identical for both machines.